# Angular translate, Using staticFilesLoader not working

Tags: meteor, angular-translate

I'm trying to localize my app with angular translate.

here are my modules :

```
angular.module('myapp', [
'angular-meteor',
'ui.router',
'ngMaterial',
'ngMessages',
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
    'pascalprecht.translate'
]);
```

Then my config :

```
angular.module('myapp').config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {

  $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'client/lib/translation/',
        suffix: '.json'
    });

        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en-US');
    }]);
```

my en-US.json file content :

```
{
  "TITLE" : "hello"
}
```

And I'm testing it with this html :

```
    <h1> {{"TITLE" | translate}}</h1>
```

I tested it with a table in a variable and it works well, the issue seems to be that my .json is not found or ignore, because it display

> TITLE

instead of

> hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the issue, I had to put my locales files in the public folder. So this is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on the same issue. What it seems to be is that the digest cycle is running too early due to the external file/s being loading asynchronously.

A workaround: In your HTML use the attribute directive instead.

Example:

```
<p data-translate="TITLE"></p>
```

Disclaimer: This may not be the best solution, I am still learning AngularJS myself!

Comment: Thanks Le-roy, but not working for me. still display TITLE.

Comment: Is it loading the file OK? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Hmm, no, I don't have any error in the console. Actually I don't really have any track to start debug it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fully working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ibq4EaFcvyUPGpqb81Jo?p=preview
To use a translation one can also use something like

```
{{"TITLE" | translate}}
```

or:

```
<h2 translate="TITLE"></h2>
```

I also had issues with loading the files, I eventually found the starting path seems to be the www folder.
Then in the config start without a forward slash, so this is what works for me in my app config:

```
.config(function ($translateProvider) {
  //$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage("en");
  $translateProvider.determinePreferredLanguage();

  $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'js/translations/locale-',
    suffix: '.json'
  });
  $translateProvider.use('en_US');
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');
})
```

I found it by using the chrome debugger (chrome://inspect), it shows errors in the console that are not showing up in the usual terminal when running ionic with -lc.

I hope that helps anyone :)!